# In the lyrics of ‘Into the unknown’

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, lyrics

There’s a phrase saying: “Everyday’s a little harder, as I feel my power grow”

Isn’t it supposed to be ‘grows’ instead of ‘grow’ going by the fact that ‘my power’ is considered as 3rd person singular?

Comment: No, it uses the infinitive in that construction. The only two correct forms of *grow* in that construction are *grow* and *growing*. In a different construction (*my power grows daily*) you would be correct. But here, the fact that it's preceded by *as I feel* changes things.